# MySQL generating duplicate UUID

Tags: mysql

I use the Mysql UUID() function to generate unique IDs.

However, I have come across a situation where it has generated a duplicate UUID. I was under the impression that if the entries were done at separate times , that this would not occur.

In this particular case, the insert queries were run a day apart and yet they have duplicated the UUID.

I can't set the field index to *unique* to ensure uniqueness, so given that this has happened, how do I ensure that UUID is generating a unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

You could fairly easily create a loop in SQL to get a UUID, check the table to ensure it doesn't exist and either use it and break the loop or loop again to get a new UUID. There have been a couple of bugs in previous versions of MySQL that caused duplicate UUIDs to be generated but the odds are crazy small, like 1 in 17 billion, that you would get a duplicate unless something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem with random hash generators. The root of the problem is that they do not remember what they created in the past. I had to add JS code to solve 2 problems.
 1. A hash value with too many numbers or letters bunched together. I used regex to track this problem. This can create 'harmonics' and make it easier to break any code using this hash.
2. The second issue was your problem and the answer I came up with was a text table that records all used hash's. If either problem occurs (it now scans the table to see if it created that hash value before), then a trigger occurs which runs the program again until neither error occurs.
 It will keep running until the answer is unique, which takes a few milliseconds at most.
Over time the library of 'used' UUID's will become huge, but it would take a million entries to seriously slow it down. Then it depends on how much CPU 'horsepower' you can throw at it. It would still be worth a delay of a couple of seconds to have a valid UUID.